# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NGXLoggerHttpService -> HttpBackend]:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I keep getting the following error after upgrading my NgxLogger module:

```
main.ts:17 NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NGXLoggerHttpService -> HttpBackend]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NGXLoggerHttpService -> HttpBackend]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpBackend!
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { RecaptchaComponent } from 'ng-recaptcha';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

RecaptchaComponent.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
};
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { metaReducers, reducers } from './core.state';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthEffects } from '../modules/auth/auth.effects';
import { CustomNGXLoggerService, LoggerModule, NGXLogger, NGXLoggerHttpService } from 'ngx-logger';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([
      AuthEffects
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [
    NGXLogger,
    NGXLoggerHttpService,
    CustomNGXLoggerService
  ]
})

export class CoreModule {
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from './modules/auth/auth.service';
import { ReferralService } from './modules/referral/referral.service';
import { UserService } from './modules/shared/services/user.service';
import { UtilService } from './modules/shared/services/util.service';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { NavbarModule } from './modules/shared/components/navbar/navbar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './modules/shared/components/footer/footer.module';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoggerModule } from 'ngx-logger';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/main/main.module#MainModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NavbarModule,
    FooterModule,
    CoreModule,
    LoggerModule.forRoot(environment.logging),
    NgxUiLoaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UtilService,
    UserService,
    ReferralService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that error because your `NGXLoggerHttpService` is depend on `HttpBackend` class but `HttpBackend` class did not import to your `providers` section in your module.ts. Try to import `HttpBackend` to your provider.

Comment: Alternatively, you can import `HttpClientTestingModule`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/issues/137), importing `HttpClientModule` and adding it in the imports of the module solves the problem

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
imports: [ ..., HttpClientModule, ...]
```